# Run .sql external file when installing extension in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, database, install-script

I have an .sql file which contain a lot of insert data, and i want import this .sql file to current magento 2 database file, everytime my custom extension finish installing and creating all custom table needed , here's the .sql file example:

```
INSERT INTO custom_table1 (name,status) VALUES ('test','active');
##....46000 rows more like this
```

Comment: do you want programmatically import sql in your custom extension InstallSchema.php?

Comment: @BilalUsean yes basically

Comment: you can use InstallData  http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/02/09/installation-and-upgrade-scripts-in-magento-2/

Comment: I know this is old, but still wondering how to acheive this in a safe way.

Answer (score 1):

Backup Magento Module uses this function in order to rollback sql files (previously backed up) I think it might help `\Magento\Framework\Backup\Db::rollback` :

```
/**
 * Implements Rollback functionality for Db
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function rollback()
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    $this->_lastOperationSucceed = false;

    $archiveManager = new \Magento\Framework\Archive();
    $source = $archiveManager->unpack($this->getBackupPath(), $this->getBackupsDir());

    $file = new \Magento\Framework\Backup\Filesystem\Iterator\File($source);
    foreach ($file as $statement) {
        $this->getResourceModel()->runCommand($statement);
    }
    @unlink($source);

    $this->_lastOperationSucceed = true;

    return true;
}
```

the resource model being `\Magento\Backup\Model\ResourceModel\Db` which have this method :

```
/**
 * Run sql code
 *
 * @param string $command
 * @return $this
 */
public function runCommand($command)
{
    $this->connection->query($command);
    return $this;
}
```

This obviously may not work well depending on the file, because magento here is sure of how the file is built, it would be interesting to look at the sql creation also  `\Magento\Backup\Model\Db::createBackup`

Answer (score -2):

The InstallSchema and InstallData classes will be run during the module install.
The InstallSchema setup script in magento 2 will be use to change the database schema (create or change database table). This’s the setup script to create the mageplaza_post table:

**File: app/code/Company/Modulename/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Setup;

class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * install tables
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('table_name')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('table_name')
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'post_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary'  => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                ],
                'Post ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'name',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable => false'],
                'Post Name'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'status',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                1,
                [],
                'Post Status'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                [],
                'Post Created At'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                [],
                'Post Updated At'
            )
            ->setComment('Post Table');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Looking into this file we will see:

The class must extend **\Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface**

The class must have **install()** method with 2 arguments **SchemaSetupInterface** and **ModuleContextInterface**. The **SchemaSetupInterface** is the setup object which provide many function to interact with database server. The **ModuleContextInterface** has only 1 method **getVersion()** which will return the current version of your module.

In the example above, we create a table named **table_name** with columns: **post_id, name, status, created_at ....**

**InstallData** will be run after the **InstallSchema** class to add data to the database table.

**File: app/code/Company/Modulename/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $_postFactory;

    public function __construct(\Company\Modulename\Model\BlogFactory $postFactory)
    {
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $data = [1
            'name'      => "Sample title 1",
            'status'    => 1
        ];
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        $post->addData($data)->save();
    }
}
```

Thank you.